Should we prevent using tags ending on -ing?
We have both tagging and tags on meta at the moment. These should definitely be merged.
Meta Stack Overflow uses tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags
Additionally I think it could be a good idea to prevent using tags ending on -ing as a basic rule. A separate discussion can always be started if a certain -ing tag were to be more suitable.

I went ahead and changed all [tag:tagging] tags to [tag:tags].

That sounds reasonable.
If "tags" is the correct tag, then we should use that.
I imagine the issue may also evolve organically. i.e., where there are two or more variants of a word for a tag, one will be more natural. At some point also we should be able to create tag synonyms.
